# How do you use the grow method in java

Tags: java, methods

Use the `grow()` method to modify a  rectangle to be twice as large.

I'm not sure if this is correct so if it is wrong please explain and feel free to correct me.

```
Kim.grow(5,8);
System.out.println(Kim);
```

Does this mean that my rectangle will now be twice as big if I code it like this or am I missing something?

grow(int 8, int v)....what would v be?..Im guessing h is the height

Comment: We need waayy more information to answer your question: can you give us some more code?

Comment: There is no standard `grow()` method. We need more information about where this method came from. Also, how is the `Kim` variable defined?

Comment: Looking at the poster's other question, it seems that he is talking about a java.awt.Rectangle

Comment: yes i am talking about the rectangle class

Comment: well for more info i know that my area is 40 and my perimeter is 26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Javadocs, the [`grow(int h, int v)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#grow%28int,%20int%29) method re-sizes your rectangle such that:

> ..it is h units larger on both the left and right side, and v units
>   larger at both the top and bottom.
>
> The new Rectangle has (x - h, y - v) as its upper-left corner, width
>   of (width + 2h), and a height of (height + 2v).
>
> If negative values are supplied for h and v, the size of the Rectangle
>   decreases accordingly. The grow method will check for integer overflow
>   and underflow, but does not check whether the resulting values of
>   width and height grow from negative to non-negative or shrink from
>   non-negative to negative.

I'm assuming that *Kim* is an instance of java.awt.Rectangle of dimensions (x, y)

Comment: How do I apply this? my width is 5 and my height is 8.